# Deploying umbraco to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, nuget, umbraco

Has anyone had an issue similar to this when deploying **Umbraco 6.1.6** to **Azure**:
My web app was set up using nuget if that makes any difference.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (2291): Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\a\src\MyProject\MyProject\Umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config;\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config

I also get a warning:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1696): Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Answer (score 2):

It's an oldie, but it's goldie, as I still had this issue for 7.5
The solution:

Inside project dir, if the file ProjectName.wpp.targets does not exist, create it. Make sure that the content will include:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
 <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>  
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The file doesn't even have to be included in the project.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

There is more information on this question at the [Our Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/60222-Umbraco-721-Build-fails-after-deploy-to-Azure-WebSite) Site.  But, I had to update the XSLT web.config build.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete or exclude this folder:
`C:\a\src\MyProject\MyProject\Umbraco\Install`

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue, we will have this fixed for v6.2.0.

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4510